# Error on pyodbc and Teradata

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, teradata, pyodbc

I have teradata 16.00 odbc driver installed on ubuntu 14.04.
If I run:

```
/opt/teradata/client/16.00/bin/tdxodbc64
```

I can connect and query.
I'm trying to connect with python thorough pyodbc=3.0.10:

```
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 12:22:00) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I can connect to the teradata DDBB but I get an error any time I try to execute a query:

```
>>> import pyodbc
>>> pyodbc.pooling = False
>>> connection=pyodbc.connect('DSN=XXX;UID=XXX;PWD=XXX',ANSI=True,autocommit=False,encoding='utf-8')
>>> curs=connection.cursor()
>>> sql="select tablename, databasename from dbc.tables"
>>> curs.execute(sql)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')
```

If I put a wrong UID or PWD on the connection I get an instant error when i execute:

```
>>> connection=pyodbc.connect('DSN=XXX;UID=XXX;PWD=WRONGXXX',ANSI=True,autocommit=False,encoding='utf-8')
```

so the ubuntu is asking Teradata for the credential. 
I don't know what is wrong when I execute any query.
Any help??

my odbc.ini driver definition is:

```
[XXXX]
Driver=/opt/teradata/client/16.00/lib64/tdata.so
Description=Running Teradata V14.10
DBCName=x.x.x.x
SessionMode=Teradata
NoScan=Yes
RunInQuietMode=Yes
StCheckLevel=0
DateTimeFormat=AAA
LastUser=
Username=
Password=
Database=XXX
DefaultDatabase=XXX
CharacterSet=UTF8
```

Thanks!!!